# How to convert value of a String into it's specific datatype? '5' -> 5 OR 'a' -> a

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

Consider I take a input as a python list and it contains values like
**`['1', '5', 't', 'John', '3.18']`**

How to convert every value into its specific data type?

Something like this

```
String '1' -> Integer 1

String 't' -> Char 't'

String '3.18' -> Float 3.18
```

Comment: Well, all elements are in their specific type, in this case - `str`. What do you understand under `it's specific data type`? e.g. 'True' - is this str `'True'` or presumably should be converted to bool `True`? Also, there is no specific `char` type

Comment: Checkout this string methods, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum

Identify the type & apply casting..

Comment: I want to check or convert String '1' to Int 1

Comment: @Tejas FYI Python does not have a char type. `type("asdf")` is `<class 'str'>` and `type("asdf"[0])` is also `<class 'str'>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for forgiveness, not permission!

```
def to_type(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return x

converted = [to_type(x) for x in your_list]
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it, by far!

Answer (score 1):

```
    values = ['1', '5', 't', 'John', '3.18']
    x=[int(value) if value.isdigit() else float(value) if value.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit() else value for value in values]
    print(x)

Output:
[1, 5, 't', 'John', 3.18]
```

1. If provided value is int it enters into if value.isdigit() and converts value into int.
2. if value is float then value.isdigit() is false and enters into if value.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit() where . will be replaced and verifies whether digit or not. If it is digits then converts into float.

Answer (score 0):

The type of data in the values list is not clear, so there is a possibility of an unexpected error.

```
values = ['1', '5', 't', 'John', '3.18']

def change_type(value):
    if str(value).isdigit():
        return int(value)
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

[change_type(value) for value in values]
```

```
[1, 5, 't', 'John', 3.18]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try except` structure to check whether an object can be converted to a specific data type:

```
l1 = ['1', '5', 't', 'John', '3.18']

#First object can be converted to int
try:
    l1[0] = int(l1[0])
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

#Second one not
try:
    l1[2] = int(l1[2])
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    
print(l1)
```

In this case, the output would be:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't'
[1, '5', 't', 'John', '3.18']
```

You can use several checking using functions like `int()`, `float()`, `bool()` .... You may need to check the Python official documentation to see all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = "123"
b = int(a)
```

Comment: That's fine for converting one value when you know its type already, but how does this help for a list with elements of different types?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to parse the elements of the list the way the Python interpreter does. The code below would also work for tuples of strings.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def convert_seq(seq):
    """Return sequence of strings into one with each parsed as a literal value."""
    def convert_elem(elem):
        try:
            return literal_eval(elem)
        except ValueError:
            return elem
    return type(seq)(map(convert_elem, seq))

r = convert_seq(['1', '5', 't', 'John', '3.18', '"100"'])
print(r)  # -> [1, 5, 't', 'John', 3.18, '100']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def check_(x):
    if "." in x:
        new_x = x.replace(".","",1)
        if new_x.isdigit():
            xx= float(x)
            return "float",xx
    if x.isdigit():
            xx=int(x)
            return "int",xx
    else: 
        if len(x)>1:
            xx=x
            return "String",xx
        else:
            xx= x
            return "char",xx

var_ = "55.3"

print(check_(var_)[0])
print(check_(var_)[1])
```